# Obtaining morethan 360 points from sweeping lidar

Tags: 3d, lidar

I mounted my lidar on a Pan and Tilt Servo Motor and trying to do the same thing just like in this site ([Lidar Lite distance measurement and creating point cloud](http://myrobotlab.org/content/lidar-lite-distance-measurement-and-creating-point-cloud)).

What I do to obtain the data is that, for every 1degree rotation of the servo motor I get the lidar reading (distance) and save it to a file. So the file consist of the X,Y and Z (distance). So therefore, in 1 revolution I get 360 points, so if I include the movement of the Y servo then i will get 360x90 (assuming X can move from 0 to 360 and Y can move form 0 to 90).

Question: Is there a way to increase a number of points getting from that sweeping lidar for every 1 degree? or I am wrong in the process of obtaining the data points?

Comment: Rather than (x,y,z) that looks more like [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), i.e. (r, θ, φ) -- radial distance (your Z), inclination/elevation (your Y, with some offset depending on how the hardware is set up) and azimuth (your X). Only with some trig will get you the Cartesian (x,y,z). It would probably be beneficial to call them the right name.

Comment: Unless you can reduce your angular step size, you won't get any more unique measurement points. You could try to take multiple samples at each position and apply some filtering to improve the distance measurements somewhat.